# Performance of `tar -xf` (block size related)

Tags: filesystems, tar, performance, io, storage

I'm recently working on optimizing the performance of `tar -xf`, i.e. untar a file.

I notice that under default settings, `tar -xf` calls `write`s to write 10 KiB output at a time in chunks. However, this causes a severe storage penalty under our current setting (using `O_DIRECT` flag with I/O for flash storage).

Is there a way to increase the chunk size that `tar` writes output files? I was playing with `-b` parameter, and noted that if I do `tar -b 512 -xvf`, the performance increases by `2x`. Is this a valid usage in this case? (The `tar` files were created under default settings.)

Is there anything else I can do to improve the throughput of `tar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-b` option in tar was used to control the block size tar writes to a device, so that is exactly what you want. But `-b 512` regarding the manual page tar(1) means a block size of 512*512 = 262144.
All block sizes are valid that your device, you write the tar output to, can handle.
In history this was needed for different tape drives the tar command was originally wrote for.

Comment: I can confirm that using `-b1024` worked when the default didn't.

Answer (score 1):

All tar implementations except `star` have performance issues that are addressed by the `FIFO` that is built into star since 1990.

Star by default creates a 8MB FIFO that helps to improve performance because star also forks into two processes. One process reads the archive and the other process does the `tar` extract task. If you are on a modern OS and using a modern tape device, I recommend to specify a larger FIFO size up to half of the physical memory of the machine. See the `star fs=` option. With modern tape drives, I recommend `fs=256M`ore more. This dramatically reduces the usual tape wear out problems from repositioning the tape when a streaming tape mode is not possible.

If you are using real tape devices, you need to increase the block size at creation time already. Note that for portability of tapes you should not use a block size > 6kB. If your local OS and drive supports larger block sizes (and not only an increased FIFO size), use larger values (see star man page).

Note that if you are using Copy on Write filesystems like ZFS or if you are on an OS with a slow filesystem buffer implementation (like Linux), you may like to switch `star` into the `insecure mode` that is only available with `gtar`. Do this by adding `-no-fsync`. On Solaris and `ufs` the star default secure mode reduces the performance by less than 10%, on ZFS and on the slow Linux buffer implementation, this secure mode reduces the performance by 400%.